# Is it possible to use .asp extension for ASP.NET code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I want to ask if it's possible to configure server to work with `.asp` extensioned files as with ASP.NET pages. Or it's absolutly denied to not mix new code with old ASP?

Comment: Why? . . . . . .  .

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, you can. though, you'll need to configure iis to do so ...

Comment: The process of registering "file extensions" can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343(v=vs.100).aspx.  But `asp` already has special meaning to IIS; attempting to remap it to mean something else seems ill advised.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but ... we have a deadline ... and ... our managers don't care about anything but production ...

Comment: Sure, and I could paint my house bright orange, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.  Tell them it can't be done... You'll be doing them a favor.

Comment: Sorry @RobertHarvey, telling somebody it just can't be done doesn't fly all the time. All you can do is inform them of the repercussions and do what they tell you.

Comment: @MikeCole: I'm the same person that commented on your answer.  The OP never explained why he needed this; you had to *guess.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I noticed that, just wanted to make a generalization on your generalization. :-)

Comment: This may seem a silly question, but isn't the reason they some files have .asp extensions is that they're classic asp files.  If what you're really asking if you can have a mixture of classic asp and asp.net files in your website then the answer is yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could place a *.asp file on your server that redirects to your final destination. I've had to do this a few times when we didn't want to break legacy hyperlinks.

Comment: This makes me feel icky, but it's probably the only correct answer.

Comment: I agree. I've done this as a quick and dirty solution when we migrated an old classic asp site to a .NET site with .aspx extensions, mostly for SEO purposes. I would monitor my error log for 404s and create .asp files that issue 301 codes. Not very elegant but it did the job.

Answer (score 3):

[Configuring Handler Mappings in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) would be the section that in theory you could specify which handler to use though this presumes you are using IIS 7.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to mix both *.asp and *.aspx pages because the configuration differs for both and my suggestion is to convert everything to *.asp /*.aspx.

Comment: I suggest to not post your private email address for such a thing, the goal is to answer the question here on SO to help as much as possible people instead of only the one who asked the question. At the end it's about the questions and answers, not social networking.